# How to create a consecutive number by month

Tags: java

I'm create a java webapp and I have to create a consecutive number that should starts every month. The idea is to have something like this:

01-0414 / 02-0414 /03-0414 / 04-0414

where the first two digits should be the consecutive number, and the last four digits are the month and year.

I'm using spring 3.2.2 and hibernate 4.2.6. I really appreciate any help about this.

thanks

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Show some code.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this problem.  Please help.

Comment: Consecutive from what? What do you have as input, and are you trying to get a string as your output? The question is very unclear.

Comment: the input is only a date, and the first number must be generate, the first number (the one before the dash) must be restarted every month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question is not clear. But as far as I understand you need help to get the date. You can use Calendar() or Date(), use something like this `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`to get the month and year (or simply parse to string and substring where you want). 
Regarding the number at the beginning, I will assume (again, since you are not clear) that it is passed as an input. So  basically you concatenate that with the "-" and the output of the previous step; the date thingy.

 I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encode your web app string using a sequence number that gets reset to 1 at the beginning of each month, you could use a singleton class instance to hold the month and sequence number state.  The code string generator method checks whether the month has changed, and if so, it resets the internal current month to the new month, and resets the effective internal sequence number to 1.

Here is the generator class (see below for an example of how to use it):

```
public class MySequenceCodeStringGenerator {
    private static final int generatorMonth;
    private static final int generatorSequenceNumber;

    // Create a singleton instance to hold month and sequence number state.
    private static final MySequenceCodeStringGenerator INSTANCE = new MySequenceCodeStringGenerator();

    private MySequenceCodeStringGenerator() {
        generatorMonth = getCurrentMonth();
        generatorSequenceNumber = 0;
    }

    /////////////////////////
    // PUBLIC functions:
    /////////////////////////

    // Get the singleton instance:
    public static MySequenceCodeStringGenerator getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    // Get the formatted sequence code string:
    public static int getSequenceCodeString {
        int sequenceNumber = getSequenceNumber();
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        String yearString = String.valueOf(year);
        return String.format( "%02d-%02d%s", sequenceNumber, month+1, yearString.substring(2) );
    }

    // Get the current month:
    private int getCurrentMonth() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        return now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    }

    // Get the singleton sequence number.  Update if this is a new month.
    private int getSequenceNumber() {
        currentMonth = getCurrentMonth();
        if ( currentMonth != generatorMonth ) {
            generatorMonth = currentMonth;
            generatorSequenceNumber = 0;
        }
        return ++generatorSequenceNumber;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how you use the generator class:

```
String myWebAppString = MySequenceCodeStringGenerator.getInstance().getSequenceCodeString();
```